# XSLT When condition for multiple OR condition

Tags: xslt

Currently, I have a working version of below code which check if first or second entry from input payload meets the condition. How can I make changes if I need to check for multiple entries instead of adding many OR conditions (i.e: [3], [4], [5]....etc) ?

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="(wd:Entry[1]/wd:Item = 'ABC' or wd:Entry[2]/wd:Item/@wd:Descriptor = 'ABC')">
        <wd:Type_Reference>
            <wd:ID wd:type="Type_ID">DEF</wd:ID>
        </wd:Type_Reference>
    </xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use e.g. `wd:Entry/wd:Item = 'ABC'` you are checking that at least one `wd:Entry/wd:Item` is equal to `'ABC'`.

Similarly `wd:Entry/wd:Item/@wd:Descriptor = 'ABC'` would check that at least one `wd:Entry/wd:Item/@wd:Descriptor` attribute is equal to `'ABC'`.

If you want to check a certain range, then, in XPath 2 and later, you can use e.g. `wd:Entry[position() = (1 to 5)]/wd:Item = 'ABC'`.